# Access violation exception c#

Tags: c#, access-violation

This is my code that throws an exception, it just randomly started today here is the photo :

[image]

Here is the whole page code and the error exception :

```
 public frmWFDocumentDetail()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        NavigationInTransition navigateInTransition = new NavigationInTransition();
        navigateInTransition.Backward = new TurnstileTransition { Mode = TurnstileTransitionMode.BackwardIn };
        navigateInTransition.Forward = new TurnstileTransition { Mode = TurnstileTransitionMode.ForwardIn };

        NavigationOutTransition navigateOutTransition = new NavigationOutTransition();
        navigateOutTransition.Backward = new TurnstileTransition { Mode = TurnstileTransitionMode.BackwardOut };
        navigateOutTransition.Forward = new TurnstileTransition { Mode = TurnstileTransitionMode.ForwardOut };
        TransitionService.SetNavigationInTransition(this, navigateInTransition);
        TransitionService.SetNavigationOutTransition(this, navigateOutTransition);

        DataContext = App.ViewModel_WFDocumentDetailItems;
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        //**this is how you pass parameters through to a new page**//
        string processID = "-1";
        string processName = "";
        NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("processID", out processID);
        NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("processName", out processName);

        App.ViewModel_WFDocumentHeaderItems.LoadData("johnny", processID);

        App.ViewModel_WFDocumentDetailItems.LoadData("johnny");

    }
```

and the access violation :

> *System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory
>   is corrupt.*

I have read up on it, some people say it is nvidia network manager, and some people say I must set some setting like Suppress JIT optimization , and ignore gpu memory if value isn't changed... but nothing works? Can anyone please please send me in the right direction?

As requested , the full stack

[image]

Comment: Can you paste the complete stacK?  Hit the "View Details" button, then paste the full stack(obfuscate any company name, or identifying verbage).  That exception is giving you the last 'steppable' line, if you go to "Debug -> Options and Settings -> Debugging -> General -> Enable Just My Code" you will stop in the actual location.  This may be the difference between an answer and no answer.

Comment: is this picture what you needed? :)

Comment: Man, don't post the stack as a picture of the watch window, that's completely useless. Instead, catch the exception, call `ToString()` on it, and post the returned text.

Comment: @taylorjonl! THAT worked awesomely that setting! it took my right to the xaml error i got, it was all a missed "</" that was the main problem!

Comment: @Arrie, screenshots are great for human consumption but us coders love text...  Strangely, I see your StackTrace is null, meaning it couldn't walk the stack.  Normally there will be a value there, that along with the message and exception type is critical to debugging exceptions.

Comment: well now i know! its kinds stupid of me to have put in a picture! won't happen again :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i used the setting taylorjohnl gave me "Debug -> Options and Settings -> Debugging -> General -> Enable Just My Code",and then the error went right to the piece of xaml that was a syntax error, and boom fixed it and app works again :) so violation error for me was basically a reference error, hope this can help other people as well, also use expression blend in silverlight to debug xaml in the UI

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem which in the end was resolved by submitting crash dump to MS Tech Support. Here is their response:

The gist is that The crash is a known bug in the version 5.0 of comctl32.dll (Windows Common Controls), which ships with the Windows OS. This bug will not be fixed in version 5.0 of the common controls, because that version was for applications existing prior to Windows XP. It has since been fixed in version 6.0 of comctl32.dll, which is included with Windows XP and later. Note that both versions of comctl32.dll (5.0 and 6.0) are included with every version of Windows since Windows XP. The older one is just there for backwards compatibility purposes for very old applications.

To resolve the problem, you need to change the application to have it opt into version 6.0 of comctl32.dll. Within a Windows Forms application, this is done by calling into the Application.EnableVisualStyles method at startup of the application. If you are developing within a C# project, then you can do this by adding the call prior to your Application.Run call within your application's entry point. For example:

```
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();   //Add this line
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
```

If you are in a Visual Basic .Net project, you can opt into this by going to your project properties, and then selecting the "Enable Application Framework" and "Enable XP Visual Styles" checkboxes on the Application property page.

Once you do this, it should resolve this particular access violation.

Answer (score -1):

what is code in the InitializeComponent()? there is some class refer to null in it, (mostly is a event handler). once it is trigger, it will report AccessViolation.

Comment: InitializeComponent is generally generated code that handles UI initalization.  He hasn't changed this code unless he specifically navigated the file system to the .g.cs file to make changes.

Comment: from your picture , the error looks happen in there. sometimes when you change the event handler by yourselves, it may cause this issue.