# UWP - Update TCP-Connection-Status from another Thread in TextBox

Tags: c#, textbox, uwp, task, observable

I have got the following code for my TCP-Connection. I don't know if it runs correctly asynchronously, so i added the Task.Delay(1000) in order to let the method receive the result, save it to "result" and afterwards give it to the UI.

My question is, how do i bind the string "result" to my textbox. I want the textbox to refresh in the UI-Thread as soon as "result" gets the result from the Connect(...)-method.

```
public static async Task Connect(string ip, int port) {

            result = string.Empty;

            DnsEndPoint hostEntry = new DnsEndPoint(ip, port);


            Socket _socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);


            SocketAsyncEventArgs socketEventArg = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
            socketEventArg.RemoteEndPoint = hostEntry;


            socketEventArg.Completed += new EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs>(delegate (object s, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
            {

                result = e.SocketError.ToString();    
            });


           _socket.ConnectAsync(socketEventArg);
            await Task.Delay(1000); 

        }
```

The Code-Behind XAML

```
            await TCPConnection.Connect(_con.IpAddress,port);
            tbConnectionText.Text = "Connectionstatus: " + _con.IpAddress;
            tbConnectionStatus.Text =TCPConnection.result;
            tbConnectionText.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            tbConnectionStatus.Visibility=Visibility.Visible;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write the bind and use the NotifyProperty to change the TextBox.

Writing the Result string in ViewModel that the task will change it when end.

The ViewModel should  inherit [NotifyProperty](https://github.com/lindexi/UWP/blob/master/uwp/src/Framework/Framework/ViewModel/NotifyProperty.cs) and the property use OnPropertyChanged in set.

```
public string Result 
{
    set
    {
         _result=value;
         OnPropertyChanged(); 
    }
    get
    {
         return _result;
    }
}

  public static async Task Connect(string ip, int port)
  {

        result = string.Empty;

        DnsEndPoint hostEntry = new DnsEndPoint(ip, port);


        Socket _socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);


        SocketAsyncEventArgs socketEventArg = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
        socketEventArg.RemoteEndPoint = hostEntry;


        socketEventArg.Completed += new EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs>(delegate (object s, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
        {

            result = e.SocketError.ToString();    
        });


       _socket.ConnectAsync(socketEventArg);
        await Task.Delay(1000); 
        Result=TCPConnection.result;
    }
```

You can bind the TextBox

```
        Binding bind=new Binding()
        {
             Path = new PropertyPath("Result"),
        };
        bind.Source = ViewModel;
        bind.Mode=BindingMode.OneWay;
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(TextBox,TextBox.TextProperty, bind);
```

If you only use Main.xaml.cs

You also can use bind in Main();

```
        Binding bind=new Binding("Result");
        bind.Source = this;
        bind.Mode=BindingMode.OneWay;
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(TextBox,TextBox.TextProperty, bind);
```

And you should make the Main inherit INotifyPropertyChanged

You should write follow in your code

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void UpdateProper<T>(ref T properValue, T newValue, [CallerMemberName] string properName = "")
    {
        if (Equals(properValue, newValue))
        {
            return;
        }

        properValue = newValue;
        OnPropertyChanged(properName);
    }

    public async void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = "")
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        await CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
            () => { handler?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name)); });
    }
```

Comment: but I don't have a ViewModel. I only have got the tcp class and the mainpage.xaml.cs

Comment: `public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            btnBroadcast_pressed = false;
            Binding bind = new Binding();
            bind.Source = TCPConnection.result;
            bind.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
            BindingOperations.SetBinding(tbConnectionStatus, TextBox.TextProperty, bind);
        }`
the last function throws an Access.Violation.Exception

Comment: @David What is tbConnectionStatus? in xaml?

Comment: the textbox which i want to bind to string result in my tcp class. Furthermore `new Binding("Result")` does not work because there is no constructor with 1 argument.

Comment: @David http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13578396/access-violation-exception-c-sharp

Comment: @David BindingOperations.SetBinding(tbConnectionStatus, TextBox.TextProperty, bind); throw it?

Comment: 1 yes, BindingOperations.SetBinding(tbConnectionStatus, TextBox.TextProperty, bind); throws it

Comment: @David The tbConnectionStatus is TextBox?

Comment: @David I change my answer.

Comment: `BindingOperations.SetBinding(TextBox,TextBox.TextProperty, bind);` -- the first argument should be `tbConnectionStatus` (the TextBox) ?

Comment: @David I fix the bind cant use path.And you can use tbConnectionStatus.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, bind);

Comment: but result is a property in an other class. So do i write "TCPConnection.resul" instead of "Result" ?

Comment: If you write the TCPConnection.resul , you should write TCPConnection   inherit INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: should i implement something in the TCPConnection class ? I only wrote `public class TCPConnection : INotifyPropertyChanged`. And everything else is in the Main.xaml.cs, right ?

Comment: Furthermore, i still got this exception  at `BindingOperations.SetBinding(tbConnectionStatus, TextBox.TextProperty, bind);`

Comment: @David You can instead it to `tbConnectionStatus.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, bind); `

Comment: Good @David .I have a program ,can you help http://stackoverflow.com/q/43602038/6116637